# How to push FacesMessages to one user

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have two users: user & admin

Is there any way to display a message (notification) in the admin screen when he is logged in,when the user add a new record ( click a command button)?

I found that i can achieve this by sending push notification but i don't know how to do that .

Comment: Basically follow the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/facesmessage.jsf).

Comment: thx ,but in the showcase  there's sample demonstrates: how to push FacesMessages to all subscribers. but i want to push message to just one user

Comment: Just only subscribe that user. Then that user will only receive the messages.

Comment: why don't you check the role of `admin` and display messages only to him?